# Switching Polarity from 12V Voltage Regulator Pair with MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, low-power

I'm trying to make a low-power (<30 uA) voltage boost board to boost a 3.7 V battery to 12V, that includes the capability to reverse polarity at a very low frequency (alternating every ~10 min), with 3.3 V logic from a separate PCB. To minimize the logic complexity and consequent power consumption, I've duplicated the voltage boost chips and included a MOSFET so that when one is enabled the output on the other is pulled to ground.

I had this chip fabricated and noticed that when I drove the logic pins high, it was pulling a confusing amount of current from the power supply (> 1 A), and I was wondering if this was an issue with transistor selection or something more fundamental to my logic. I really appreciate the help!

[image: Circuit Schematic]

Comment: This is the MOSFET datasheet for reference, https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntk3134n-d.pdf

Comment: Is the > 1 A current drawn just on the transition from one polarity to the other, or is it continuous whenever either LOGIC A or LOGIC B is high?
If it's a short surge it could be because you are shorting the output of the regulators before they have time to shutdown, if it's continuous it may be that the regulators aren't happy with their outputs shorted even while disabled.

Comment: It's continuous, and it occurs even when I start up one of the regulators for the first time (so when they both were low to start and then one gets driven high)

Comment: The voltage regulator datasheet indicates a OUT, LX to GND range of -0.3V to +22V, so it should be able to handle being pulled to ground. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX17291B-2887633.pdf

Comment: I would scope it and see if you've got an oscillation.
Did you simulate it ?

Comment: Why don't you use an h-bridge to switch the polarity of *one* voltage regulator?

Answer (score 0):

You must not pull both of your control inputs high at the same time. Both voltage regulators will be enabled with their outputs shorted to ground (the gates of the MOSFETs are driven high!). You either need to account for that in your software or do it in hardware using a NOT gate.

Beside that you also have to make sure that the voltage regulators are shut down when activating the MOSFETs. You could add a RC network to the gates to give the MOSFETs some delay (don't enable the regulators while the MOSFETs are not saturated).

In case you don't know what an [H-Bridge](http://actually%20a%20pretty%20big%20deal%20on%20e.g.%20an%20Arduino%20Uno) is, I suggest you take a look at it. That's often used to switch polarity.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help! The software prevents both logic pins from being driven HIGH at the same time at the moment. 

Right now there is no way to delay enabling the regulator, since the enable pin is tied to the same net as the MOSFET gate. What would be the reason for adding that delay in? Since the Gate-Source and Drain-Source voltages are within specification throughout the cycle period.

Comment: I decided against an H-bridge to keep my component count and power consumption down, since any off-the-shelf one would have far too high of a power consumption. Since these voltage regulators have a shutdown current of 13 nA, I can use less power by running one at a time.

Comment: @OctaviusPublius It's not about the voltage ratings. The reason is that the regulator will take some time to switch states, especially from high to low because of the output capacitance. The MOSFETs switch much faster and are shorting the output (which still holds charge/voltage!) to ground. Components are not infinitely fast, which you have to keep in mind.